# How to differentiate touch and mouse events in QML

Tags: android, qml, qt5

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true

    onClicked: {
           /// is it from touch or mouse?
    }
}
```

I see some issues in android like **enter & press** and **exit & click** events are happening simultaneously on TOUCH.

So is there any way to differentiate these two?

Comment: Use [MultiPointTouchArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html) with  `mouseEnabled: false` along with `MouseArea` and so process mouse and touch events separately.  From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html#details): _if the mouseEnabled property is set to false, it becomes transparent to mouse events so that another mouse-sensitive Item (such as a MouseArea) can be used to handle mouse interaction separately._

Comment: I think, you can also create a C++ class, that if created in QML registers a `eventFilter` to the parent mouse & touch sensitive object. There you can get the "raw" events.

Comment: @folibis Thank you folibis for reply, MultiPointTouchArea helps me a bit but it is not skipping MouseArea onEnter and onExit fuction except onClick