# In QML, what methods are available to prevent mouse drag events inside a ListView (excluding the scrollbar)?

Tags: qml

In ListView, some blank areas may capture mouse drag events, which then trigger scrolling, interfering with text selection or other operations. Is there any way to disable such events? I want scrolling to be triggered only when interacting with the scroll bar or using the built-in mouse wheel or touchpad gestures. Can anyone provide some ideas or solutions? Thanks！

Comment: Have you tried just putting a MouseArea over the ListView that catches mouse events and ignores them?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting interactive to false, which indeed disables all mouse events. Therefore, do I need to define the wheel event myself to make the scroll wheel or touchpad effective?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you still want the scroll wheel and touch input to work, not just the scrollbar.

Comment: Maybe the suggestions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543370/how-to-differentiate-touch-and-mouse-events-in-qml) will help?

Comment: You need to use the [DragHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-draghandler.html#acceptedDevices-prop) and its `acceptedDevices` property to restrict input devices to only the `TouchScreen`. And yes, you should set the `interactive` property to false.

Comment: You could eliminate the blank areas by sizing your ListView to the dimensions of your content, e.g. `ListView { width: contentItem.children[0].width; height: childrenRect.height }`.

Comment: I just add ```DragHandler { target: null }``` to the ListView and it works for me, thank you all！